# Javascript dit not trim and hide the div after i activate other function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this function (*1) and its work perfectly before i add another function (*2). I dont know what is conflicting... :(

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() {
        $('#iframe').load(function() {            
            if ($.trim($(this).contents().find("body").html()) == "") {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<iframe id="iframe" width="100%" height="48" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="http://www.oranews.tv/breaking.php"></iframe>
```

With the only first function on my header the function its working perfectly.
When i add the second function on the index.php the first function did not work anymore.

```
(function (e) {
    if (typeof popwid == "undefined") return;
    e.post(popwid.ajaxurl, {
        postid: popwid.postid,
        action: "popwid_page_view_count"
    })
})(jQuery);
jQuery(document).ready(function (e) {
    e.noConflict();
    try {
        e("div.pop-inside ul").hide();
        e(".pop-widget-tabs").each(function () {
            tabid = e(this).attr("id").replace("pop-widget-tabs-", "");
            e("#pop-widget-tabs-" + tabid + " a").eq(0).addClass("active");
            e(".pop-inside-" + tabid + " ul").eq(0).show()
        });
        e(".pop-widget-tabs a").click(function () {
            tab = e(this).attr("href").replace("#", "");
            id = e(this).parents(".pop-widget-tabs").attr("id").replace("pop-widget-tabs-", "");
            e("#pop-widget-tabs-" + id + " a").removeClass("active");
            e(this).addClass("active");
            inx = e("#pop-widget-tabs-" + id + " a").index(e(this));
            e(".pop-inside-" + id + " ul").hide();
            e(".pop-inside-" + id + " ul").eq(inx).show();
            return false
        })
    } catch (t) {
        return false
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you format the code to make it more readable in your second example?

Comment: Please take the time to format your code properly. It will make it much easier for others to read and help you with.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? `e.noConflict()` will be one I imagine.

Comment: i found this error on console @RoryMcCrossan 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined (index):425
(anonymous function) (index):425
f.event.dispatch jquery.min.js:3
h.handle.i

Comment: `noConflict` is intended to be used when you use some other library besides jQuery in your code, so what's that library? can that library really conflict with jQuery? BTW, better include tag with that library in your question.

Comment: @KingKing that's true, however `noConflict` needs to be called on the jQuery variable, usually `$`, not an event inside a handler.

Comment: So any answer how can i fix it guys? :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes, I'm not sure about its usage, I just want to mean he may use some other library here but he did not mention it. Not sure why he could use `noConflict` that way, I doubt that the library he is using may even not have any possible conflict with jQuery.

Comment: @KingKing its a plugin for wordpress called Popular Widget, so i have no idea why the author use noConflict.. :/ I just know is when i activate the plugin my first function not hiding the iframe anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Removed the e.noConflict(); did the trick.

Thank you guys anyways.

```
(function (e) {
    if (typeof popwid == "undefined") return;
    e.post(popwid.ajaxurl, {
        postid: popwid.postid,
        action: "popwid_page_view_count"
    })
})(jQuery);
jQuery(document).ready(function (e) {
    try {
        e("div.pop-inside ul").hide();
        e(".pop-widget-tabs").each(function () {
            tabid = e(this).attr("id").replace("pop-widget-tabs-", "");
            e("#pop-widget-tabs-" + tabid + " a").eq(0).addClass("active");
            e(".pop-inside-" + tabid + " ul").eq(0).show()
        });
        e(".pop-widget-tabs a").click(function () {
            tab = e(this).attr("href").replace("#", "");
            id = e(this).parents(".pop-widget-tabs").attr("id").replace("pop-widget-tabs-", "");
            e("#pop-widget-tabs-" + id + " a").removeClass("active");
            e(this).addClass("active");
            inx = e("#pop-widget-tabs-" + id + " a").index(e(this));
            e(".pop-inside-" + id + " ul").hide();
            e(".pop-inside-" + id + " ul").eq(inx).show();
            return false
        })
    } catch (t) {
        return false
    }
})
```